# Gson initialize new variables

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I have a class model where there are already multiple saved users in a json file, and i want add a new variable, that variable is transient so it is not serializable by gson, that works but when I deserialize a user from the database using gson.fromJson, then i try to use the variable it tells me that it is null but I am in fact initializing it.

```
public class User {

private final String name;
private final String lastName;

private final transient Map<TypeBuy, String> checkout = new HashMap<>();

public User(String name, String lastName) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public void addCheckout(TypeBuy typeBuy, String price) {
    checkout.put(typeBuy, price); // error here, says checkout is null / not initialized
}
```

Comment: It is possible that when you are creating a `Gson` instance with `GsonBuilder`, you called the `excludeFieldsWithModifiers(int... modifiers)` without including `Modifier.TRANSIENT`. This method overrides the default setting (to ignore transient fields), and if you did not include `Modifier.TRANSIENT` in the arguments, the transient fields will undergo deserialization too.

Comment: @Bernard no, i dont use excludeFieldsWithModifiers, transient is already excluded by default

Comment: Do you mind adding the code where you deserialize the objects and also where you invoke `addCheckout`?

Comment: This might help you: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html

Comment: Still need help.

Comment: The reason is probably that your `User` class only has a constructor with parameters. Gson will then create instances using JDK's `Unsafe` which does not call any constructors (and also does not initialize the fields). You could probably solve this by adding a `User() { }` constructor so Gson can invoke that.